# Should my question be posted on SO or Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked [Is the Entity Framework appropriate when all you do is insert records in bulk?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112674/is-the-ado-net-entity-framework-appropriate-when-all-you-do-is-insert-records-in) over at Programmers; however, I just don't know if that is where the question should go.

I feel that my question is more of a technical question about the limitations of the Entity Framework. However, when I close questions to migrate on Stack Overflow I always say "Stack Overflow is for sitting in front of the computer coding question and Programmers is for in front of the whiteboard type question" and I feel that this is a "in front of the whiteboard" question.

What do you guys think? Is my question a Stack Overflow, or a Programmers question? 
 It will help me in the future in deciding which site to post to.

Comment: Looks like a Programmers.SE question to me.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes there's overlap, and a question fits fine in either place.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's good to break down definitions and criteria for "If I'm doing [activity1] I'll post on SO, if I'm doing [activity2] I'll post on Programmers". But allow me to submit different criteria.

- If I'm sitting in front of my computer OR in front of a white board, I'll post on SO.
- If I'm in a meeting or dealing with lots of post-it notes, I'll post on Programmers.

Now, I could still see something like this being in a meeting at a high level. After all, what framework you're going to use can be a big issue with lots to consider, requiring input from a lot of different teams, making it more of managerial decision. (Let us hope your management is better at technical decisions than mine?) But I agree with you that this is a whiteboard question.

I fully admit I could be the only person who feels that way about those definitions. :-)